# GET and POST in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have problem in sample page that will retrieve student id from the url ' update.php?id=1' to use it in query , when I write the id manually in the query it's worked .. can't figured out

update.php

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
$id=$_GET['id'];
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$pdo=Database::connect();
$sql="UPDATE students SET name=? , mobile=? WHERE id=?";
$q=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name,$mobile,$id));
Database::disconnect();
header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<h3>Update Student Information</h3>
</div>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<div>
<label>Name</label>
<div>
<input name="name" type="text">
</div>
</div>
<div>
<label>Mobile No.</label>
<div>
<input name="mobile" type="text">
</div>
</div>
<div>
<button type="submit">Add</button>
<a href="index.php">Back</a>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE : To make this clear the id retrieve from url address from other page like I said not from the html form ... url ' update.php?id=1' how should I do it ?

index.php

```
 <?php
 include 'database.php';
 $pdo = Database::connect();
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM students';
 foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>'. $row['mobile'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td><a href="show.php?id='. $row['id'].'">Show</a></td>';
 echo '<td><a href="update.php?id='. $row['id'].">Update</a></td>';
 echo '</tr>';
 }
 Database::disconnect();
 ?>
```

Comment: You use `$id=$_GET['id'];` `GET` but your form is `POST`?!

Comment: To make this clear the id retrieve from url address from other page like I said not from the html form ... url ' update.php?id=1' how should I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

To see what error the PDO throws, add the following code:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

also you should add these (at the top of your file):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Another idea: Maybe the stuff from post is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Why not send the id variable with the POST form as well?

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="x">
```

Then retrieve it with `$_POST['id']` instead of `$_GET['id']`

Comment: To make this clear the id retrieve from url address from other page like I said not from the html form ... url ' update.php?id=1' how should I do it ?

Comment: You don't have to send the id in the URL (which is what GET does), you can send it in the POST form instead.

Answer (score -2):

your didnt use $id in your query
it should be some thing like $sql="update students SET name=? , mobile=? WHERE id=".$id." "

Comment: Hello, have a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)